# Detecting line by color using Opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture( Basic X-Y plot image, where the plot line is in blue color and x,y axis are in black color), where in that I need to detect the edges based on the color. I came across below code, where its detecting all the lines by using canny edge detection and hough algorithm. But I need to detect only the blue color line in this image. What can i do in order to detect that?

Below is the code that I used.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('xyplot.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('grayimage',gray)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imshow('edgesimage',edges)
print img.shape[1]
print img.shape
minLineLength=img.shape[1]-300
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=0.02,theta=np.pi/500,    
    threshold=10,lines=np.array([]),                                 
    minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=100)
a,b,c = lines.shape

for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2],
        lines[i][0]   [3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: picture showing graph]

Answer (score 0):

Apply a (blue) color mask on your image before converting to gray scale. You can do so by defining the lower and upper boundary of all 3 channels and performing BITWISE_AND on the original image. You will have to play around with the values of the channel ranges to make sure only the pixels you want get captured.

```
lower = np.array([200, 20, 20], dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array([255, 100, 100], dtype = "uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
```

Note: The three channels in the list are B, G and R respectively.

Comment: Use my snippet after the line:
img = cv2.imread('xyplot.png')

Comment: Since the image is computer-generated in your case, you can set the color ranges close to _pure_ blue.

Comment: I got it masked, but only half of the line got masked. Not fully. How to make it masked fully?

Comment: What are the lower and upper values that you are using? Try playing around with those values so that it covers a larger range of shades of blue

Comment: I have used the same values as u used for the above image

Comment: These values work for the graph image you shared
lower = np.array([150, 0, 0], dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array([255, 0, 0], dtype = "uint8")

Comment: But i dont know why am not able to get the output.I am getting an error message as "not responding" only if i change the values

Comment: After playing around with the values, I think the following values will work in your case: lower = np.array([200, 0, 0], dtype = "uint8")
upper = np.array([255, 150, 150], dtype = "uint8")

Comment: The reason you are getting a "not responding error" is because there is a bug in your code at (a,b,c = lines.shape). If no line is detected, the variable lines will be None and trying to access variable: shape of None will cause an error. Write a check before this statement that makes sure line is not None.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your help as it really helps me.